# Web scraping in Selenium in Python - find elements via xpath or id return empty list

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape a list of email addresses from my User Explorer page in Google Analytics.

which

[I obtained the x-path via here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v74eJ.png)

The item's X-path is `//*[@id="ID-explorer-table-dataTable-key-0-0"]/div`

But no matter how I do:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(`//*[@id="ID-explorer-table-dataTable-key-0-0"]/div`)
```

or

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ID-reportContainer"]')
```

or

```
driver.find_elements_by_id(r"ID-explorer-table-dataTable-key-0-0")
```

it returns an empty list.

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

I also tried using:

```
html = driver.page_source
```

but of course I couldnt find the list of the emails as well.

I am also thinking, if this doesnt work, whether there is a way I can automate control + a and copy all the text displayed into a string in Python and then use`re.findall()` to find the email addresses?

Comment: It either dynamic ID or, more likely, inside `<iframe>`.

Comment: @Guy you are right! Its iframe! Thanks! I resolved it and my answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help of @Guy!

It was something related to iframe and this worked and detected which frame the item i need belong to:

```
iframelist=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
for i in range(len(iframelist)):
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframelist[i])
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ID-explorer-table-dataTable-key-0-0"]/div'))!=0:
        print('it is item {}'.format(i))
        break
    else:
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

email = driver.find_element_by_xpath(`//*[@id="ID-explorer-table-dataTable-key-0-0"]/div`)

print("email", email.get_attribute("innerHTML"))

Comment: This will throw an error, you can't use `get_attribute` on a list. And the OP used the exact same `xpath`, why would it work now?

Comment: ya this one doesn't work at all! I think @Guy you should right! it is something to do with iframe potentially! Let me test a bit!

Comment: sorry，i Wrong reading.   but@See can test Chrome plugins ： XPath Helper ,   you can see your Xpath , check it for mistakes